# Advertising academic jobs in Academic SE

Tags: feature-request

I've seen that stackoverflow has one section for advertising jobs. I think it would be very interesting to have a similar thing here for academic open positions.

Please check http://careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I fear it might be less useful, because academic open positions are so specialised.

Comment: @gerrit The same applies for stackoverflow jobs. They have  a search engine and you can specify the region, type of contract, and field.

Comment: I find the proposal interesting, however one potential issue is that universities might wish to menage this stuff directly.

Comment: And if the advertising is handled privately by the community members there can be a bias: I might not be willing to advertise a position in my field in which I wish to apply... not that I fear competition, of course ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would be great if there was a single place where jobs were generally advertised. While I generally widely disseminate jobs in my department, the reach of AC.see is so small, that I would never consider doing it here. Additionally, job adverts do not fit the Q/A nature of our site and a search committee does not want to get involved in a discussion about the position.

If you know about jobs, I say post away in chat. Maybe even make a dedicated chat room if you want.

I am inclined to say they do not belong on the main board, but if we as a community want a single big-list job wiki type question (possibly one per field and year), then I could see if working. That said, I think job wikis are really awful and our format would not improve it. If you want to go that route, ask a new meta question with a detailed description of what you are proposing. Just so you are clear, while as a mod I do what the community wants, I would most likely down vote such a proposal.

Comment: Please check http://careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @MojtabaEbrahimi careers.so is a very different site from the standard SE site. Potentially SE would create a sub-site like careers.academia.stackexchange.com, but I think search committees do a bad job of advertising and if it costs money to post would be even more reluctant.